Angular router reuse strategy class - inject service
I am posting new question based on the following conversation:
Original question
Here is the code provided in the original question:
      import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
  })
  export class DetachedComponentTrackingService { }
  The strategy would look similar to:

  import { inject } from '@angular/core';
  import { 
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
    RouteReuseStrategy 
  } from '@angular/router';
  import { 
    DetachedComponentTrackingService 
  } from './.../detached-component-tracking.service';

  export class DetachedAwareRouteReuseStrategy 
    extends RouteReuseStrategy {

    private readonly functionInjectedService =
      inject(DetachedComponentTrackingService);

    constructor(
      private readonly constructorInjectedService: DetachedComponentTrackingService
    ) { 
      // RouteReuseStrategy
      super();
    }

    override shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
      // this.functionInjectedService...
      // this.constructorInjectedService...
      throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }

    // Other overrides...
  }
  Then just provide the strategy like any other provider token:

  import { AppComponent } from './.../app.component';
  import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
  import { 
    DetachedComponentTrackingService 
  } from './.../detached-component-tracking.service';
  import { 
    DetachedAwareRouteReuseStrategy 
  } from './.../detached-aware-route-reuse-strategy';

  bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
      {
        provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
        useClass: DetachedAwareRouteReuseStrategy,
      },
      provideRouter([
        // Routes...
      ]),
    ],
  });

I have followed it and compiled it ok, but when I run it I am getting:
    main.ts:18 Could not load file 'assets/config/config.dev.json': {"name":"NullInjectorError","ngTempTokenPath":["InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS",
"[object Object]","Router","RouteReuseStrategy","DetachedComponentTrackingService","DetachedComponentTrackingService"]} 

and pages are not loading.
If I try injecting a service that is located in the same root folder where awa-route-reuse-strategy.ts is then it works fine. Any idea how to make it work with a service located anywhere in the app?
Thanks

what is the file assets/config/config.dev.json suposed to be?

That is an in-house implementation to configure dev environment after the builds. I am not entirely sure how it works; I wasn't the one who implemented it.

maybe you should inspect this file as it is a problem loading this file, maybe there is a fetch somewhere.

Agree, anything possible. But this file is read at the loading time and no complains there. As far as I understand it is just global configuration settings that are available via a service anywhere in the app.
